# IF-ELSE statement: create a column depending on another one

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, plsql, sql-update

In the table JAN07, I have a column TEMPO_INTERCORSO (number(10,0)) and I want to create another column ANTE_POST (number(1)) that is '0' when TEMPO_INTERCORSO > 0 and '1' otherwise.

```
IF (TEMPO_INTERCORSO > 0) THEN
   UPDATE JAN07 SET ANTE_POST = 1
ELSE
   UPDATE JAN07 SET ANTE_POST = 0
END IF;
```

I've tried a lot of different ways that you can find on the web (for example the ";" before the ELSE: [sometimes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/controlstructures.htm#BABGBDCB) there is, [sometimes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/04_struc.htm#484) not), but it is still not working.

```
IF (TEMPO_INTERCORSO = 0) THEN
Report error -
Comando sconosciuto
```

Some ideas?

ps= I've tried with JAN07.TEMPO_INTERCORSO too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following `UPDATE` query uses `CASE...WHEN` to achieve what you want:

```
UPDATE JAN07
SET ANTE_POST = CASE WHEN TEMPO_INTERCORSO > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: I'm sorry not to have found the reason for my IF-structure not working, but..... thanks! I've solved with your solution!

Answer (score 2):

I would rather suggest **[Virtual Columns](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#BABCHBHE)** introduced in `Oracle Database 11g Release 1`. A simple **CASE** statement would do the rest.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t
  2    (
  3      TEMPO_INTERCORSO NUMBER,
  4      ANTE_POST        NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
  5      CASE
  6        WHEN TEMPO_INTERCORSO > 0
  7        THEN 1
  8        ELSE 0
  9      END) VIRTUAL
 10    );

Table created.
```

Now, you need not worry about manually updating the virtual column, it will be automatically generated at run time.

Let's **insert the values only in static column** and see:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO t(TEMPO_INTERCORSO) VALUES(0);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(TEMPO_INTERCORSO) VALUES(1);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(TEMPO_INTERCORSO) VALUES(10);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

TEMPO_INTERCORSO  ANTE_POST
---------------- ----------
               0          0
               1          1
              10          1
```

So, you have your column `ANTE_POST` with desired values automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional control [IF-THEN-ELSE STATEMENT](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/if_then.php) is one statement in PL/SQL. Each statement in PL/SQL ends with semi color. Hence it's written like this:

```
IF condition THEN
   {...statements to execute when condition is TRUE...}

ELSE
   {...statements to execute when condition is FALSE...}

END IF;  --semi colon at the end
```

In your code, there is an update *statement* **inside**. Therefore, at the end of this statement there must be semi colon. Your code can be written like this:

```
IF (TEMPO_INTERCORSO > 0) THEN
   UPDATE JAN07 SET ANTE_POST = 1;  --semi colon
ELSE
   UPDATE JAN07 SET ANTE_POST = 0;  --semi colon
END IF;  --semi colon
```

Some answer already suggested doing that in pure SQL rather than PL/SQL. Which I agree with.

Comment: Although you are right about the structure, this misses a lot of implications from the fact that the OP is using a field name in the condition; you can't use it there, even if you could all rows would be updated to the same value, etc, etc.